# Rotate Pie Label in dc.js Pie Chart

Tags: javascript, dc.js

[image]Let's say I have the following code in dc.js to create a pie chart:

```
var chart = dc.pieChart("#test");
d3.csv("morley.csv", function(error, experiments) {
  var ndx           = crossfilter(experiments),
      runDimension  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return "run-"+d.Run;})
      speedSumGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.Speed * d.Run;});
  chart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .slicesCap(4)
    .innerRadius(100)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(speedSumGroup)
    .legend(dc.legend())
    // workaround for #703: not enough data is accessible through .label() to display percentages
    .on('pretransition', function(chart) {
        chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice').text(function(d) {
            return d.data.key + ' ' + dc.utils.printSingleValue((d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (2*Math.PI) * 100) + '%';
        })
    });
  chart.render();
});
```

What I want to do is rotate the label, but when I do so, all of the labels translate to the center of the pie.

```
chart.renderlet(function (chart) {
    chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice')
    .attr('transform', 'rotate(315)');
});
```

Is there a way to rotate the labels without changing their position on the graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're replacing the `transform` attribute for these elements, which is currently used to "translate" the labels in position.

Since it's hard to dig into the calculations used here, I think the best approach is to pull the existing transform attribute and modify it, like this:

```
chart.on('renderlet', function (chart) {
    chart.selectAll('text.pie-slice')
        .attr('transform', function(d) {
            var translate = d3.select(this).attr('transform');
            var ang = ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI)%360;
            if(ang<180) ang -= 90; else ang += 90;
            return translate + ' rotate(' + ang + ')';
        });
});
```

For my own entertainment, I've also rotated the labels using the start and end angles of the pie slices.

It's unfortunate you can't do this as a pretransition event and avoid the "jump". It will just get overwritten by the animations. Doing this properly would require some changes to dc.js - [file an issue](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new) if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

addition to Gordon's answer, for all pieCharts to have this feature; i changed labelPosition function in dc.js.

```
return 'translate(' + centroid + ')';
```

to

```
var ang = ((d.startAngle + d.endAngle) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI)%360; 
if(ang<180) ang -= 90; else ang += 90; 
return 'translate(' + centroid + ') rotate(' + ang +')';
```